# CITE-Seq-Count Trimming Fastq files / Running Comma Separated List

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fastq

I'm using the program CITE-seq-Count to analyze cell hashing/cite-seq data. We had a sequencing run of AdT/HTOs on multiple lanes (1-4). I tried merging the fastq.gz files with the cat function and while running them as below:

```
CITE-seq-Count 
-R1 ./adt_read1/merged_adt_S2_L005_R1_001.fastq.gz 
-R2 ./adt_read2/merged_adt_S2_L005_R2_001.fastq.gz ... (tags, cells, etc).
```

and I receive the error: Sequence length in ./adt_read2/merged_adt_S2_L005_R2_001.fastq.gz is not consistent. Please, trim all sequences at the same length. Exiting the application.

I see that in 1.4.3 version of CITE-seq-Count there is the possibility to use multiple lanes (and not merge the .fastq.gz files)

```
Inputs:
  Required input files.

  -R1 READ1_PATH, --read1 READ1_PATH
                        The path of Read1 in gz format, or a comma-separated list of paths to all Read1 files in gz format (E.g. A1.fq.gz,B1.fq,gz,...
  -R2 READ2_PATH, --read2 READ2_PATH
                        The path of Read2 in gz format, or a comma-separated list of paths to all Read2 files in gz format (E.g. A2.fq.gz,B2.fq,gz,...
```

but when I try to run with the code below, it fails.

```
CITE-seq-Count
-R1 ./adt_read1/ADT703_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz , ./adt_read1/ADT703_S2_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz , ./adt_read1/ADT703_S2_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz , ./adt_read1/ADT703_S2_L004_R1_001.fastq.gz 

-R2 ./adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz , ./adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz , ./adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz , ./adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L004_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I receive an error saying those arguments are unused. Is there a way to incorporate all lanes L001-4 into one run? Is my comma-separated list incorrect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this command. To fix your command: remove white space such as blanks around the comma (`foo , bar` -> `bar,bar`), add `\` (backslash with **no trailing whitespace**) at the end of each line for a command that spans multiple lines.

```
CITE-seq-Count \
-R1 ./adt_read1/ADT703_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz,./adt_read1/ADT703_S2_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz,./adt_read1/ADT703_S2_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz,./adt_read1/ADT703_S2_L004_R1_001.fastq.gz \
-R2 ./adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz,./adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz,./adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz,./adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L004_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Hi! Removing the whitespace was helpful however I'm now stuck with the original problem regarding trimming the fastq files: ``` [ERROR] Sequence length in adt_read2/ADT703_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz is not consistent. Please, trim all sequences at the same length.
Exiting the application.```

Comment: Maybe post it as a separate question, as is the SO convention, to get the solution faster. I also noticed your post here: https://github.com/Hoohm/CITE-seq-Count/issues/97 .

Comment: The most likely root cause is in fact different read lengths in your input, for whatever reason (trimming was my first guess, but you say they are not trimmed). To fix the issue with the input, either (a) remove the shorter reads, or (b) trim all reads to the shortest read length, depending on the distribution of lengths and/or the quality of the results with CITE-seq-Count using (a) or (b) as input. For read length histogram, there are several tools, e.g., https://www.biostars.org/p/274998/#275001 , https://www.biostars.org/p/72433/ .